# How to get active user database table in WOffice theme wordpress theme

Tags: php, android, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am using WordPress for my website with woffice theme. I am developing an android app for the above website. It is required to get database of active user with last login detail. If someone know how to display the active user list, please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you will need to build a api

Comment: Can I get some help to build the api? Is that not possible to get active user database table? It is possible to list the active user in android by fetching database and retrieving it as a json array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get the posts or texts of the page by using json api like Ideapress api plugin in wordpress. And retrieving the json response in android app.
Thank you for every one who helped me to get the answer. I hope, this answer could help others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get these informations in the frontend, you can try to use a plugin like : https://wpdatatables.com/

With this plugin, you can easily add a result from a query from your database (Source : https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/creating-new-wpdatatables-with-table-constructor/generating-wordpress-db-queries-with-table-constructor/)

Comment: I am not clear with your answer.

You can see my site active member list here http://www.bdsskarnataka.org/members/

I just need, how to get the last seen detail thats it.